# Iso 27K Implementation

Tags: risk-management, risk-analysis, network-access-control, iso27000

Suppose we buy a new cisco router or any IT equipment. How can we employ ISO 27k/NIST 800-37/NIST 800-53 or any other related information security management standards technically? I mean what should we do about it? Should we install software to check its vulnerability? Or should we check that the equipment has well known vulnerabilities and obviate them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a compliance advice (ISO 27001) ? Or just for any hardening / secure configuration guidelines?

Comment: I just want to obtain technical systematic view about implementing these standards. Then, I will know how to face with risk of malware, web attacks, sniffing and etc more technically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Build the system according to the vendor's configuration guide. Look at NIST, SANS, Centre for Internet Security for security benchmarks for the product and harden the system.
2) Follow industry best practice for unique user names, role based access control, strong password policies.
3) Enable configuration backups and diffs to identify unintended or malicious changes, enable logging and review.
4) Run a vulnerability scanner against the system IP and see if there are known vulnerabilities; remediate these.

The above will cover you for industry best practice.. ISO, NIST, PCI etc

Comment: Thank you so much Andy. Am I right: After adding a new equipment to the organization, we should check probable vulnerabilities and overall viable attacks which can be orchestrated from that device (using standards and expert knowledge) and define controls to address them? Btw, Can we find the complete approach (technical one) in NIST and similar standards. Please suggest some sources for reading to have technical/applied view about these topics (I mean realistic one) to be able to implement them.

Comment: @Mostafa the process I outlined above is based on a mixture of PCI DSS and ISO27001 - you could have a look through those standards and security controls within ISO27005. In terms of considering attacks, you'd check attacks that could be run against that device as opposed to from it - the vulnerability analysis should assist in identifying these.